# Permission to write /system

Tags: android, permissions, system-setting

I'm writing an application that needs to write /system. I have been doing it through busybox (Using commands), but now I'm building with firmware keys, so I have access to all system permissions (via android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system")

I have sucessfully added permissions like this ones

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

But I can't seem to find on SDK or not even on AndroidManifest.xml for frameworks/base/core/res, a permission that allows this. I'm on SDK 15, building Android 4.0.4 from sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there's not permission defined on SDK for doing this, neither on frameworks. I found that the best way is to use Settings.System for storing the values with a provider